# Snaping Puzzle Pieces like MIT Scratch

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, interface

I'm trying to create a kind of puzzle interface where blocks can easily snap together. The interface would be similar to something like [MIT scratch](https://vimeo.com/65583694) in that a block needs be able to expand if more blocks need to fit inside. I was wondering what a good way to do this might be or if something similar already exists?

My idea so far on how to implement this is to make blocks just UIViews the user can drag around. I'll make them snap together if they come close to each other. As for the expanding part, that's a bit tricky, I could have those blocks be made of 3 views. When more space is needed I could expand the middle sections and the gap and fit the blocks. Anyways this seems extremely tedious to implement and honestly does not appear to be that efficient. Is there not an existing object / open source library I can piggy-back on to make this easier?

Comment: I don't think that efficiency should be your chief concern, because the user's interactions with UI elements aren't going to tax the CPU.

Comment: Please post a picture of your code or some material to help us? Your question isn't really clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any libraries that can do this magically for you, but what I would do is have a list of open connections where a block or piece could fit, and when you release the mouse button, the piece you have selected goes to the nearest positions (use the pythagorean theorem to find distances). and maybe you have threshold distance at which the block doesn't actually snap in place. Yes the expanding would be slightly more difficult, but in the end you could just use a CGPath that is redrawn when something is placed in the function.

here is a bit of an example.

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distanceTo(_ other:CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(sqrt((pow(other.x - self.x, 2) + pow(other.y - self.y, 2))))
    }
}
```

that would be the distance function that I have pasted into most of my programs.

```
var pieces:[NSView]!//The Pieces on the board/screen
var SelectedPiece:NSView!//the piece you are holding, could also be an index.
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    var spaces:[CGPoint] = []
    for piece in pieces {
        spaces.append(CGPoint(x: piece.frame.origin.x, y: piece.frame.origin.y + 20))//change 20 to whatever
        spaces.append(CGPoint(x: piece.frame.origin.x, y: piece.frame.origin.y - 20))
        //if you are actually making a puzzle you might want pieces on the sides.
    }
    var ClosestDist:CGFloat?
    var ClosestIndex:Int?
    for space in spaces {
        let dist = space.distanceTo(SelectedPiece.frame.origin)
        if closestDist != nil {
            if dist < closestDist {
                ClosestDist = dist
                ClosestIndex = spaces.index(of:space)
            }
        }else {
            ClosestDist = dist
            ClosestIndex = spaces.index(of:space)
        }
    }
    if ClosestDist! < 15 {
        SelectedPiece.frame.origin = spaces[ClosestIndex]
    }
}
```

This is obviously incomplete, but I hope this helps!